# Blazor Application stuck "Loading..." in UWP WebView

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, blazor

I am trying to display a Blazor application (The default Blazor template, hosted on a server) in a Xamarin Forms UWP WebView however it gets stuck "Loading...".

If I debug the UWP application (attaching to Script) I get the following exceptions thorwn:

JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 716 in https://localhost:7131/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error.

```
JavaScript critical error at line 99, column 13 in https://localhost:7131/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js\n\nSCRIPT1005: Expected '('

Exception was thrown at line 38, column 60610 in https://localhost:44399/c9828a2102ba4dafa1d62c9962b407b5/browserLink
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
```

Comment: I believe this is a compatibility issue with the WebView using EdgeHTML instead of Chormium.

Trying to find a way to use WebView2 or Polyfills in Blazor Web Assembly

Comment: So far my options look like abandoning Blazor Web Assembly or wait until MAUI is released and migrate my Xamarin Forms to that.

Comment: Did you meet the problem on the other platforms(such as Android)?

Comment: No I'm fairly certain its due to the Xamarin Forms WebView using old Edge in UWP.
Trying to find a way to use WebView2 with XamarinForms

Comment: Have you checked this [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663978/how-i-can-use-webview-2-in-xamarinfrom.html)? It seems that the WebView2 can be used in the uwp.

Comment: I have been able to create a Xamarin ContentView in my UWP project and set the content as a WebView2 (using the Xamarin native ToView() method, and wrapped in a Grid). I have then injected that into my Xamain.Forms project.
If I get the chance I will post the full solution.